# Getting lowest and highest value in PHP array not showing me the correct numbers

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 124,95
    [1] => 139,95
    [2] => 149,95
    [3] => 1200
    [4] => 150
    [5] => 154,95
    [6] => 130
    [7] => 189,95
    [8] => 199,95
    [9] => 30
    [10] => 150
)
```

And I am trying to get the lowest (30) and highest (1200) numbers from it.

So I did this:

```
while($getpricesproducts = $getpricesproductscon->fetch_assoc()){
  $prijsarray[] = $getpricesproducts['prijs'];
}

// Lowest and highest price to put in price slider
$prijslow = min($prijsarray);
$prijshigh = max($prijsarray);

echo $prijslow;

echo $prijshigh;
```

`$prijsarray` is above array.

But the echoed values are 30 as min number and 150 as max. Why is that? Does it have something to do with the commas in some numbers? Still it is weird that 1200 is not the max number since it does not have any commas.

Comment: Yes the comma is the issue. As I said 30 minutes ago. NUMBERS should be stored on the database in an appropriate number TYPE and in sensible mathematical format i.e. `123.45` Yours are strings

Comment: because it consider that those are string, i believe the coma disturb the rank for the max also. you should parse them to float and then do the max function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to convert all the numbers in your array from their current format to floating point. Then you can take the `min` and `max` and use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to convert them back to your format:

```
$new_array = array_map(function ($v) { return (float)strtr($v, array(',' => '.', '.' => '')); }, $array);
echo number_format(min($new_array), 2, ',', '.') . "\n";
echo number_format(max($new_array), 2, ',', '.') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
30,00
1.200,00
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NE2ln)

Comment: This also has issues with larger number like `1.222.333,45`

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly I've corrected the code and updated the demo

Comment: @twan I've updated my answer, there was an issue with numbers with `.` in them which I've fixed.

Comment: Thats got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code as below:

```
while($getpricesproducts = $getpricesproductscon->fetch_assoc()){
    $prijsarray[] = (float) str_replace(',', '.', $getpricesproducts['prijs']);
}
```

But as other commented, it would be better if you fix your database to store prices as floating numbers.

Comment: Why replace the `,` with `.`? I guess `explode` is what needed here... (as not sure if `154,95` means `154.95` or 2 number of `154` and `95`

Comment: This also may have a problem with `1.000.123,99`

Answer (score 0):

As said in max function documentation:

> Values of different types will be compared using the standard
>   comparison rules. For instance, a non-numeric string will be compared
>   to an integer as though it were 0, but multiple non-numeric string
>   values will be compared alphanumerically. The actual value returned
>   will be of the original type with no conversion applied.

So, you could try to convert all values to float before inserting to your array:

```
while($getpricesproducts = $getpricesproductscon->fetch_assoc()){
  $prijsarray[] = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $getpricesproducts['prijs'])); 
}

// Lowest and highest price to put in price slider
$prijslow = min($prijsarray);
$prijshigh = max($prijsarray);

echo $prijslow;

echo $prijshigh;
```

Comment: except just using  `floatval()` will truncate all the strings at the first `,` so you will infact be converting all the numbers to integers.

Comment: you're right @RiggsFolly. I've fixed my code, now it's okay.